# função de pesquisa em Laravel retorna erro TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php

Tags: php, laravel

Boa noite amigos, sou novato no laravel e estou precisando construir uma função para pesquisa de dados de uma tabela, fiz algo baseado no que entendi até este momento, mas esta me retornando a seguinte mensagem de erro **TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67:**quando é solicitado a rota. abaixo segue o código:

routes.php

```
Route::post('clientes/pesquisa', 'ClientesController@pesquisa');
```

ClientesController.php

```
public function pesquisa(){
        $pesq = Input::get('pesq');
        $resultado = Tb_clientes::where('idempresa', 1)->where('nome', '=',$pesq)->get();
        return view('clientes.index')->with('tb_clientes', $resultado);
    }
```

O local de chamada da rota

```
<form class="form-inline" method="post" role="form" action="/clientes/pesquisa">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label >Pesquisar:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="pesq">
                          </div>
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></button>
                        </form>
```

Estou fazendo certo ou tem uma maneira mais fácil?

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt. Acesse a Ajuda e faça o Tour. Aqui no caso desta questão você precisa apresentar parte do teu código. Edite a pergunta e insira o código abaixo dela. Será mais fácil te ajudar.

Comment: Editado. Obrigado

Comment: Perfeito! Bom trabalho! Não deixe de marcar a resposta que te atendeu de alguma forma (ou a melhor entre elas) e votar nas perguntas e respostas que forem importantes parta você.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu primeiro e mais importante passo é ler a maior parte possível da [documentação oficial](https://laravel.com/docs/master/installation) (se não a documentação inteira), acredite, a documentação é e sempre sera sua melhor companhia.

Antes de realizar uma pesquisa você deve aprender a construir uma nova aplicação do zero, definir as configurações iniciais da sua aplicação e configurar seu ambiente de desenvolvimento. Posso adiantar que você vai precisar definir e configurar o seu banco de dados, suas rotas básicas, seus modelos, e, só então, criar, ler, atualizar e deletar estes dados.

Em relação a nossa comunidade, gostaria de te dar as boas vindas e reforçar uma parte do texto de introdução que diz o seguinte:

> Concentre sua atenção em perguntas sobre um problema real que você
>   enfrentou. Inclua detalhes sobre o que você tentou e exatamente o que
>   você está tentando fazer.

Sua questão está muito simples e incompleta, procure nos informar o que você já tentou e em quais pontos você está com maiores dificuldades. Não se esqueça de utilizar a pesquisa ali em cima para procurar perguntas relacionadas e que talvez também funcione para você (tente também o nosso bom e velho amigo Google).

Se por final você ainda estiver com problemas, tente editar sua pergunta e acrescentar mais detalhes.

Espero que isso tenha te ajudado de alguma forma, vou deixar alguns links interessantes que encontrei com uma simples pesquisa no Google, relacionados a Laravel.

- [Laravel Brasil](http://www.laravel.com.br/)
- [Webschool](https://github.com/Webschool-io/Curso-PHP-Laravel-Completo-E-Total)
- [Learning Laravel](http://learninglaravel.net/tags/tutorials)

E não poderia deixar de te indicar o [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/).

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado Rafael, vou primeiro dar uma olhada na documentação conforme indicado, já configurei banco rotas e etc, só preciso implementar a pesquisa em uma página, mas primeiro vou dar mais uma olhada e caso não consiga colocarei aqui o que tentei. Obrigado

Comment: Combinado @FilipeGuedes, mais uma vez bem vindo a nossa comunidade. Uma sugestão a mais, veja se consegue seguir o tutorial da documentação oficial onde você constrói uma simples (ou avançada) [lista de tarefas](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart).

Answer (score 1):

Galera já está resolvido só coloquei  input

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

deu certo!

Comment: Fico feliz que tenha conseguido, sua questão ficou melhor após as alterações.